# Why isn't CSS :focus pseudoselector working as expected in Chrome?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple form. When the user focuses on an input, the label should move up. It works fine in Firefox (as can be seen in video), but not in Chrome. In chrome, the text is stuck in the end position. When I change text color in the :focus + span code block, it applies automatically, which tells me that the elements are constantly focused.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function PersonalInfo() {
const [firstAndLastName, setfirstAndLastName] = useState(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('FirstAndLastName' ?? '')));
const [email, setEmail] = useState(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('email' ?? '')));
const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('companyName' ?? '')));
const [companyIndustry, setCompanyIndustry] = useState(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('companyIndustry' ?? '')));

const handleNameChange = (e) => {
  // console.log(firstAndLastName)
  sessionStorage.setItem('FirstAndLastName', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  setfirstAndLastName(e.target.value)
}

const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
  // console.log(email)
  sessionStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  setEmail(e.target.value)
}

const handleCompanyNameChange = (e) => {
  // console.log(companyName)
  sessionStorage.setItem('companyName', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  setCompanyName(e.target.value)
}

const handleCompanyIndustryChange = (e) => {
  // console.log(companyIndustry)
  sessionStorage.setItem('companyIndustry', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  setCompanyIndustry(e.target.value)
}


  return (
    <PersonalInfoContainer>
      <InputContainer>
        <Input 
        name="user_name" 
        type='text' 
        value={firstAndLastName} 
        onChange={handleNameChange} 
        placeholder=''/>
        <Label>First and Last Name</Label>
      </InputContainer>
      <InputContainer>
        <Input  
        name='user_email' 
        type='email' 
        value={email} 
        onChange={handleEmailChange} 
        placeholder=''/>
        <Label>Email</Label>
      </InputContainer>
      <InputContainer>
        <Input 
        name='user_companyName' 
        type='text' 
        value={companyName} 
        onChange={handleCompanyNameChange} 
        placeholder=''/>
        <Label>Company Name</Label>
      </InputContainer>
      <InputContainer>
        <Input 
        name='user_companyIndustry' 
        type='text' 
        value={companyIndustry} 
        onChange={handleCompanyIndustryChange} 
        placeholder=''/>
        <Label>Company Industry</Label>
      </InputContainer>
    </PersonalInfoContainer>
  )
}

const PersonalInfoContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 30vh;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
`;

const InputContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Label = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: .2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #e6e5e5;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.6s;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  padding: .6rem 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e6e5e5;
  color: white;

  &:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  }

  &:not(:placeholder-shown) + span,
  &:focus + span {
    color: white;
    transform: translateX(10px);
    transform: translateY(-25px);
    font-size: 0.75rem;
   } 
`;

export default PersonalInfo
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/personal-info-form-component-h9652x

Comment: Hi, your codesandbox works well!

Comment: I know! haha. But when the code is applied in Chrome, it doesn't work. I'll upload some videos on YouTube to show you.

Comment: I mean I'm using Chrome 115 but there is no error.

Comment: Firefox: https://youtu.be/CrM3QYuf94I

Comment: Chrome: https://youtu.be/8k-4cMZ7YYk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard at [13.1.3. The Placeholder-shown Pseudo-class: :placeholder-shown](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#placeholder) says:

> Input elements can sometimes show placeholder text as a hint to the user on what to type in. See, for example, the placeholder attribute in [HTML5]. The `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class matches an input element that **is showing** such placeholder text, whether that text is given by an attribute or a real element, or is otherwise implied by the UA.

In your case, however, you have `placeholder=''` as a placeholder which displays nothing. Firefox and Chrome right now don't agree on if "displaying" an empty placeholder counts as displaying. I believe that Chrome is right in that case and not Firefox.

A solution to your problem is to set `placeholder` to an actual value (which you should do anyways) and make the placeholder text transparent.

```
input::placeholder {
   color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be from:

```
&:not(:placeholder-shown) + span,
```

It works as intended if written as:

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span,
```